# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-props, react-state

[![enter image description here][1]][1][image]**Filename : productScreen.js**

**Error     : line 6 - TypeError: Object(...) is not a function**

**Path     :src/Screens/ProductScreen.js**

**Code as follows:**

```
  3 | import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
  4 | import { detailsProduct } from "../actions/productActions";
  5 | function ProductScreen(props){
  >6|     const productDetails= useSelector(state => state.productDetails);
  7 |     const {product , loading , error} = productDetails;
  8 |     const dispatch = useDispatch();
  9 |     useEffect(()=>{
  10|          dispatch(detailsProduct(props.match.params.id));
  11|         return () => {
  12|        };
  13|    } , [])
```

**Filename : store.js**

**Path     : src/store.js**

**Code as follows:**

```
    1|const initialState = {}
    2|const reducer = combineReducers({
    3|productList: productListReducer,
    4|productDetails: productDetailsReducer
    5| })
    6|const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
    7|const store = createStore(reducer , initialState , composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
    8|export default store;
```

**Filename : index.js**

**Path     :src/index.js**

**Code as follows:**

```
    ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store = {store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
    serviceWorker.unregister();
```

All imports are made correctly

Comment: Can you recreate the issue on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)? What you shared seems ok

Comment: How are you importing `useSelector`? Please include the missing lines 1 and 2 in your `ProductScreen` component. [See example usages from React Redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples).

Comment: added the image, please check.

Comment: You seem to have imported `useSelector` from `react-dom`. You need to import it from `react-redux` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're missing `useSelector` import statement.

Add `import { useSelector } from "react-redux";` in your `ProductScreen.js` file.